# How to create event for checkbox list in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How to create event for checkbox list in MVC 3
I can do this using

```
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home"))
            {
                <div>white: @Html.CheckBox("white") </div>
                <div>black: @Html.CheckBox("black") </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            }
```

but I need to do this without submit button, I need event for white and black checkbox, how to do this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by JQuery:

```
$('#white, #black').change(function() {
  $('#form_id').submit();
});
```

Comment: First thank you for the answer, but in this case how to keep all checkbox statment

Comment: @MoraruViorel: The idea is that you keep your current code, and then add the javascript to supply the event handler that submits the form. `#form_id` is here the id tag on the form rendered by `Html.BeginForm()`.